# Finding intersection of connections of many (Graph algorithm?)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph

Say I have a list of connections for 3 (or more) people. Call them Max, Jeff, and Steve.

They each have a list of connections, for example.

Max   -> Frank, Sue

Jeff  -> Sue, Jerry, Caroline

Steve -> Caroline, Alice, Bob

Given these lists I want to return any intersections that arise.

So I would return [Sue, Caroline], because Max and Jeff intersect at Sue and Jeff and Steve intersect at Caroline.

I am programming in Ruby so that may have its own cool, special way of doing stuff like this, or I will have to write my own algorithm to get these. I thought of it as a graph seen below.

[image: graph of explained connections]

So what is a good way to find these intersections given I have them in lists to begin with? Is there a good ruby way to say like: Max.connections & Jeff.connections & Steve.connections or would it be good to make a graph and sort through them like that.

Thanks!

Comment: In ruby, if I do max.connections & jeff.connections, I'll get ["sue"]. and if I do jeff.connections & steve.connections, I'll get ["caroline"], but if I do max.connections & jeff.connections & steve.connections, I get []. And it's not practical to do like: (max.con & steve.con) + (max.con & jeff.con) + (jeff.con & steve.con) because I may have a lot more to cross reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
h = {
  "Max" => ["Frank", "Sue"],
  "Jeff" => ["Sue", "Jerry", "Caroline"],
  "Steve" => ["Caroline", "Alice", "Bob"],
}
```

where each array in `h` does not include duplicates. Then, to find duplicates among the arrays, you can do:

```
h.values.flatten.group_by{|e| e}.values.select{|a| a.length > 1}.map(&:first)
# => ["Sue", "Caroline"]
```

Comment: clever, but is there not just a mathematical principle behind what I am looking for? Either way, thanks!